# Expected cost of algorithm based on hypergeometrical distribution

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, algorithms

I am having an algorithm which cost I want to determine, but I am having trouble to do so. In order to do so, I tried to break it down to a well known scenario, to be able to communicate the issue:

Let's say I have an urn with balls of $R$ different colours.
For each color there are $D$ balls in the urn, so in total there are $R\cdot D$ balls in the urn.
Now I am going to draw $m$ balls from the urn.
For some magical reasons, the maximum of balls I can draw of the same colour is $D-1$.
Let's further say there is going to be a cost evoked for each type of ball I draw that is exponential to the number of balls I draw of that type, so $g^k$, where $k$ is the amount of balls I draw of a specific colour.
Whether I draw three red balls and two black balls or three black balls and two red balls does not matter though - that is the same cost.

My goal is to find out what the expected cost is going to be.

Here are the thoughts: First one can say that the expected cost for each colour is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{D-1} p_c(k) \cdot g^k
$$
where $p_c(k)$ is the probability to draw $k$ balls of the colour $c$.
For a single color I can say that it follows individually the [hypergeometrical distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution)

$$
p_c(k) = \frac{ \binom {D}{k} \cdot \binom {R\cdot D - D}{m-k} }{ \binom {R\cdot D}{m} }
$$

I had hoped that I could say that the total cost would be

$$
R \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{D-1} p_c(k) \cdot g^k
$$

but this does not seem to be the case, as my experiments show: Here I chose $g=3, R=150, D=4$ and got for different $m$ after 100 experiments the `cost_mean`, while I expected from above formulas `cost_expected`:

```
     m  cost_mean  cost_expected
0    0     150.00     150.000000
1   30     219.96     219.208595
2   60     311.00     309.155349
3  120     566.64     555.690471
4  210    1150.32    1069.921732
5  300    1986.60    1642.216299
6  375    2903.40    1994.406183
7  450    4050.00    2020.841856
```

When thinking about it it is easy to see that $m=450=(D-1)\cdot R$ is the highest number of balls I am allowed to take out and that cost should be thus  $4050=R\cdot g^{D-1}$, so I assume the implementation of my experiment is correct, and my formulas are not.

**Where is my mistake in the formulas and what is the correct formula?**

---

*Disclaimer: This question is a follow up question of [Expected cost of algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2393638/expected-cost-of-algorithm/2394207), but since I was able to figure a lot more out since then and the answer provided there is not correct regarding the aspects asked in this question here, I decided to ask a new one with all the new content.*

Answer (score 1):

$$R \cdot \sum_{i=0}^{D-1} p_m(i) \cdot g^k$$ doesn't actually make sense because $k$ is undefined, but I assume that what you really mean is $$\sum_{c=1}^R \sum_{k=0}^{D-1} p_c(k) \cdot g^k$$ The problem is that this assumes that the $p_c$ are independent: it counts, for example, $$\sum_{c=1}^R p_c(0) \cdot g^0$$ which is the total cost when drawing $0$ balls, but you're supposed to be drawing $m$ balls.

To handle interdependence you need to sum over complete draws: i.e. $$\sum_{b_1+\ldots+b_R = m}p(b_1,\ldots,b_R)\sum_{i=1}^R g^{b_i}$$
Given that the exact order of the $b_i$ doesn't change the cost it should be possible to restructure this as a sum over partitions of $m$ with a suitable multiplicity factor in the term, but I'm not sure that you're going to get a "nice" formula.

Comment: I corrected the formula that I meant in the question. It was a typo: I meant $k$ instead of $i$ and $c$ instead of $m$ in that formula. Maybe that is the same as $$\sum_{c=1}^R \sum_{k=0}^{D-1} p_c(k) \cdot g^k$$ ?

Comment: It's effectively the same because the individual probability distribution $p_c$ is the same for each $c$.

Comment: What does this mean for me? How can I estimate the algorithmic cost of my algorithm? (Especially Big-O Notation, depending on $m$.)

Comment: Could you explain your last term?